# resize cell in xamarin

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin

[image: A cell in a TableView of Xamarin]

I have a table view built in Xamarin that is populated with some addresses, but i can't figure out how to resize the cell so that all information will fit.

***My TableViewCell Class:***

```
using System;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Drawing;

namespace Vipar
{
    public class CustomVegeeeCell : UITableViewCell  {
        UILabel Title, Addr, CityState;
        //UIImageView imageView;
        public CustomVegeeeCell (NSString cellId) : base (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellId)
        {
            SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.Gray;
            ContentView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;//(84, 84, 85);

            //imageView = new UIImageView();
            Title = new UILabel () {
                Font = UIFont.FromName("Arial-BoldMT", 16f),
                TextColor = UIColor.Black,

                BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear
            };
            Addr = new UILabel () {
                Font = UIFont.FromName("ArialMT", 12f),
                TextColor = UIColor.Black,
                //TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center,
                BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear
            };
            CityState = new UILabel () {
                Font = UIFont.FromName("ArialMT", 12f),
                TextColor = UIColor.Black,
                //TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center,
                BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear
            };
            ContentView.Add (Title);
            ContentView.Add (Addr);
            ContentView.Add (CityState);
        }
        public void UpdateCell (string caption, string subtitle, string subtitle1)//, UIImage image)
        {
            //imageView.Image = image;
            Title.Text = caption;
            Addr.Text = subtitle;
            CityState.Text = subtitle1;
        }
        public override void LayoutSubviews ()
        {
            base.LayoutSubviews ();
            //imageView.Frame = new RectangleF(ContentView.Bounds.Width - 63, 5, 33, 33);
            Title.Frame = new RectangleF(5, 4, ContentView.Bounds.Width - 63, 25);
            Addr.Frame = new RectangleF(5, 18, ContentView.Bounds.Width - 63, 25);
            CityState.Frame = new RectangleF(5, 30, ContentView.Bounds.Width - 63, 25);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In UITableViewSource, you need to override GetHeightForRow:

```
public override float GetHeightForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
```